# How to use a button press from a second JFrame in a seperate Class as an action in the main class

Tags: java, swing, jframe

So for school, we have to make 2 separate JFrames that interact with each other. From within the first JFrame, a button gets pressed which opens the second one, where a name, speed, and position can be filled in.

When pressing `OK` on the second JFrame, I save the filled-in text and numbers but I have no clue how to use them in the code of the first JFrame. I had tried to use a "getter" from the second JFrame to check in the first one if the "OK" button had been pressed. But this gets checked immediately after opening the window. That means it isn't true YET and it doesn't check it again.

CONTEXT:

- We are forced to use 2 separate JFrame.
- We are not allowed to add extra methods.
- We are not allowed to change the constructor.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TourFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private Etappe etappe;
    private JLabel jlAantal;
    private JTextField jtfAantal;
    private JButton knopPrint;
    private JButton knopStap;
    private JButton knopVoegFietsenToe;
    private JButton knopVoegCustomFietsToe;

    public TourFrame(Etappe etappe){
        this.etappe = etappe;
        setTitle("Tour de Windesheim: " + etappe.toString());
        setSize(650, 550);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jlAantal = new JLabel("aantal:");
        add(jlAantal);
        jtfAantal = new JTextField(10);
        add(jtfAantal);
        knopPrint = new JButton("print");
        add(knopPrint);
        knopPrint.addActionListener(this);
        knopStap = new JButton("stap");
        add(knopStap);
        knopStap.addActionListener(this);
        knopVoegFietsenToe = new JButton("voeg fietsen toe");
        add(knopVoegFietsenToe);
        knopVoegFietsenToe.addActionListener(this);
        knopVoegCustomFietsToe = new JButton("voeg custom fiets toe");
        add(knopVoegCustomFietsToe);
        knopVoegCustomFietsToe.addActionListener(this);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource() == knopPrint){
            etappe.print();
        } else if(e.getSource() == knopStap){
            etappe.stap();
            setTitle("Tour de Windesheim: " + etappe.toString());
        } else if(e.getSource() == knopVoegFietsenToe){
            try {
                int aantal = Integer.parseInt(jtfAantal.getText());
                for(int i = 0; aantal > i; i++){
                    Fiets tijdelijk = new Fiets();
                    etappe.voegDeelnemerToe(tijdelijk);
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
                jlAantal.setText("Voer een getal in");
            }
        } else if(e.getSource() == knopVoegCustomFietsToe){
            FietsDialoog fietsdialoog = new FietsDialoog();
        }
    }
}
```

The Second one looks as follwed:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class FietsDialoog extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JLabel jlNaam;
    private JTextField jtfNaam;
    private JLabel jlStartPositie;
    private JTextField jtfStartPositie;
    private JLabel jlSnelheid;
    private JTextField jtfSnelheid;
    private JButton knopOk;
    private JButton knopCancel;
    private String naam;
    private int startpositie;
    private int snelheid;
    private boolean ok;
    private boolean cancel;

    public FietsDialoog(){
        setTitle("FietsDialoog");
        setSize(600, 100);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);

        jlNaam = new JLabel("naam");
        add(jlNaam);
        jtfNaam = new JTextField(10);
        add(jtfNaam);
        jlStartPositie = new JLabel("startpositie");
        add(jlStartPositie);
        jtfStartPositie = new JTextField(10);
        add(jtfStartPositie);
        jlSnelheid = new JLabel("snelheid");
        add(jlSnelheid);
        jtfSnelheid = new JTextField(10);
        add(jtfSnelheid);
        knopOk = new JButton("ok");
        add(knopOk);
        knopOk.addActionListener(this);
        knopCancel = new JButton("cancel");
        add(knopCancel);
        knopCancel.addActionListener(this);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public String getNaam() {
        return naam;
    }
    public int getStartpositie() {
        return startpositie;
    }
    public int getSnelheid() {
        return snelheid;
    }
    public boolean isOk() {
        return ok;
    }
    public boolean isCancel() {
        return cancel;
    }
    public JButton getKnopOk() {
        return knopOk;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == knopOk){
            this.naam = jtfNaam.getText();
            this.startpositie = Integer.parseInt(jtfStartPositie.getText());
            this.snelheid = Integer.parseInt(jtfSnelheid.getText());
            this.ok = true;
            this.cancel = false;


        } else if(e.getSource() == knopCancel){
            this.ok = false;
            this.cancel = true;
            dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"We are forced to use 2 separate JFrame."* Really? A much simpler way to achieve it is to use a modal `JDialog` (or a `JOptionPane` - modal by default) to get the user input. That way, the values can be queried immediately after the call to set the dialog or option pane visible, and we can be sure it has been closed before that line of code runs. **Check** with teacher that they explicitly meant two **`JFrame`** instances, as opposed to (for e.g.) 'two windows'. If the answer comes back '2 frames', ask why they are making this arbitrarily difficult by using the *wrong* window for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try and print `fietsdialoog.getNaam()`, `fietsdialoog.getStartpositie()`...etc, the `getter` from the `fietsdialoog` class after closing the window.

Also, rather than dispose the window: use `setVisible` to `false`. `JFrame.setVisible(true/false);`